# Outlook 2003 to load all it's components

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

The question, I suppose, is how can I get Outlook 2003 Pro to load all it components when it first starts. I run it on Windows 8.1 Pro.

When I start Outlook it opens fairly quickly. No problem. But whatever functions I use takes a fair time, easily 10 seconds, to start when I first use it, such as open an email, delete an email, send/receive emails (mine is not set to automatic).

It appears as if Outlook starts, loading it’s core, but nothing else, and loads components only when they are needed the first time. I can use Outlook for a while, say to read emails, but when I close those and want to delete them, but have not once used the delete since starting Outlook, the delete operation takes a while to start. After the first time use all the functions start essentially immediately.

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your own email (organizations have long moved past Outlook 2003), you can:

1. Repair the PST file (if you have a PST file).
2. Archive email to make the email file smaller.
3. Once archived, if you have just an OST file (IMAP), consider backing the OST file up to another drive and rebuild the OST file.
4. Finally, upgrade to a much newer version of Outlook.

If I recall Outlook 2003 correctly, it could only maintain a small email file PST or OST (around 20 GB). Today you could be banging against that limit. Upgrading versions is the answer to that.

Comment: For some reason I can't mark the question as answered, but it is answered in what could be point 5.  The size of my file was 1.9 GB.  When I simply removed emails, it didn't change anything, but when I copied about 1 GB into a new file, Outlook 2003 behaved properly.  So, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Follow the Tour(https://superuser.com/tour) and you should be able to mark my answer that it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry John, for some reason I can't vote on an answer.  It says I need 15 reputations, but I can't vote to get these reputation.  Nevertheless, be assured that point 4. of your answer works very well for me.  I get a lot of emails, that I am not well enough organized to manage to keep my .pst file small.  Since your Jul answer I had to do 2 "new file reloads". and things work very well.  Thank You John.